# Error while using Debug Console: DeprecationWarning: The `use_readline` parameter is deprecated and ignored since IPython 6.0

Tags: python, debugging, console, pycharm

I have an issue with the Pycharm Debug console. Here's what I do step by step: I set a breakpoint somewhere in my code and when it stops at this breakpoint, I open the debug console as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-debug-console.html). This is prompted:

```
>>>
```

Then I try to do something basic like `a = 1`, but I get
[this error message (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6rNP.png). As copy-paste:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 362, in get_interpreter
    interpreterInterface = getattr(__builtin__, 'interpreter')
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'interpreter'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1443, in do_it
    result = pydevconsole.console_exec(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, dbg)
  File "C:\dev\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 467, in console_exec
    need_more =  exec_code(CodeFragment(expression), updated_globals, frame.f_locals, dbg)
  File "C:\dev\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 383, in exec_code
    interpreterInterface = get_interpreter()
  File "C:\dev\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in get_interpreter
```

When I start doing this for a whole new python file, everything works out well, but instead of the `>>>`  what is prompted is

```
In[2]:
```

Where is the difference coming from and what can I do to use the debug console in the first case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`>>>` refers to the Python console while

```
In[2]:
```

is the IPython console, a kind of console on steroids.

Sometimes, a strange import can crash one thing and not the other. Maybe you could check on this one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by pytest settings - I had set that warnings should be treated as errors.
I changed my `pytest.ini` by adding:

```
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*deprecated and ignored since IPython.*:DeprecationWarning
```

seems to solve the issue for me